# Listening to consumer-related events in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am building a Spring Boot application which consumes messages from message broker with the help of Spring Cloud Stream.
Is there any listening mechanism in Spring Cloud Stream framework, which will allow me to have callbacks / to listen to events indicating whether a consumption operation is successful or not.
I need such a mechanism to hook in and count such cases with Micrometer Counter.

Documentation of Spring Cloud Stream [has a comprehensive description of Error Handling mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling), but in my case it covers only error cases, and I would like to cover success cases as well.

Does it makes sense to do the increment of my Counter of successfully processed messages inside my consumer bean (see the code below)? I am not sure about this because consumer bean contains the business logic only. I suppose message consumption operation may also fail somewhere else in the logic of Spring Cloud Stream and I would like to count such cases as well.

```kt
@SpringBootApplication
class SampleApplication {

        val Counter success = Metrics.counter("success")
        val Counter failure = Metrics.counter("failure")

        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
          runApplication<SampleApplication>(*args)
        }

        @Bean
        fun consumer(): (Message<Payload>) -> Unit = { message ->
           System.out.println("Received: " + message.payload);
           doBusinessLogic()
           // NOT OK, will be incremented even in case of some error happened
           // in Spring Cloud Stream right after consumer function returns. 
           success.increment()
           return null
        }

        @Bean
        fun consumerErrorHandler(): (ErrorMessage) -> Unit = { error -> 
           // OK, will be incremented in any error case.
           failure.increment()
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Which binder are you using? RabbitMQ and Kafka (at least) have built-in support for Micrometer with a `Timer`s (for success and failures), these timers include a count.

Comment: It is [Azure Event Hubs binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-cloud-stream-support?tabs=SpringCloudAzure5x#spring-cloud-stream-binder-for-azure-event-hubs). Elaborated on this in [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76201053/6139804).

Comment: If someone uses Azure Event Hubs, keep in mind that apparently you still can use [Apache Kafka](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka) binder by connecting it via [Kafka API of Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/azure-event-hubs-kafka-overview). Not in my case, unfortunately, I am forced to use Event Hubs native API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RabbitMQ and Apache Kafka binders already have built-in support for Micrometer `Timer`s (for success and failures). Timers have a count property.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I have not went deeper yet to the level of particular binder since I had a feeling that something like this could be implemented one the level of abstraction Spring Cloud Stream provides (I mean success / failure counting despite the underlying message broker technology).
I am using binder for [Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-cloud-stream-support?tabs=SpringCloudAzure5x#spring-cloud-stream-binder-for-azure-event-hubs), will see if it supports some metrics...

Comment: Btw, is it some kind of a pipe dream to have such a functionality on the level of Spring Cloud Stream abstraction (perhaps due to some technical limitations / philosophy mismatch) or it could take place if someone implements this? 

Comment: It's certainly possible; but it really belongs in the core projects that the binders are based upon since the binder is an "application" from those projects' perspective and other applications would benefit from it being in the core implementation.

Comment: Makes total sense, thank you!